# Resolve a physical location to a logical location

Tags: rascal

I already found the resolveLocation() function to convert a logical location to a physical location.  Does there also exist a function to convert a physical location to a logical location?

In that case, a location with for example "|project://...", would resolve in "|java+class:///...".
I would then be able to use it in the readFileLines() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look up the mapping in both directions in the m3 model with the `.declarations` field:

```
data M3(
    rel[loc name, loc src] declarations ...
```

To look up physical from logical:

```
mymodel.declarations[logicalURI]
```

A reverse lookup requires you to invert the relation first

```
mymodel.decls<src, name>[physicalURI]
```

By the way, if your m3 model is "registered" the readFile functions will do the resolution for you and just work on any URi. Registration happens by default as a side effect from the createM3FromEclipseProject function.